# How to increment a score with sharedObject?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have been trying to make this small game in Flash using ActionScript 3.0. I'm using the SharedObject class and what I want to do is to see if it is possible to make the data type (so.data.x) null or 0 by default because by default it's not really anything. When I try to increment one of those data types, it gives me NaN or when I try to compare it I get a logic error in the "onClickSubmit" function. I can't assign anything at the beginning of the program because the whole point of it is for it to be saved after you close the game and reopen it. Thanks in advance.

```
import flash.net.SharedObject;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;

var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("app");

target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickTarget);
submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickSubmit);

function onClickTarget(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    so.data.currentHighscore++;
    trace("Clicked! " + "(" + so.data.currentHighscore + ")");
}

function onClickSubmit(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (so.data.currentScore > so.data.highscore)
    {
        trace("You beat the highscore!");
        so.data.currentHighscore = 0;
    }

    else
        trace("You haven't beat the highscore yet... keep trying");
}
```

Comment: Why do you store temporary data in a shared object? Also, your variable names past `so.data.` do not match within `onClickTarget` and `onClickSubmit`. If you refer something that's not yet in `so.data` you'll get `undefined` value and your logic will be Royally Screwed (c), so watch them closely.

Comment: @user2808631 To enable the user to memorize its scores, you should use PHP and MySQL, because the .so file can be deleted without its knowledge. See for more information: [Adobe help about SharedOject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) > Local disk space considerations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do like that:

```
import flash.net.SharedObject;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;

var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("app");

target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickTarget);
submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickSubmit);

var score:int = 0;
if (so.data.highscore == undefined) so.data.highscore = 0;

function onClickTarget(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    score++;
    trace("Clicked! (" + score + ")");
}

function onClickSubmit(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (score > so.data.highscore)
    {
        trace("You beat the highscore!");
        so.data.highscore = score;
        so.flush();
    }
    else
        trace("You haven't beat the highscore yet... keep trying");
}
```

**Remark**

You should use PHP and MySQL, because the .so file can be deleted without user's knowledge. See for more information: [Adobe help about SharedOject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) > Local disk space considerations.

Comment: Sorry I haven't been able to test the code out yet I have been really busy thi s week. I'll check it out tomorrow, thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, the "so.data.highscore == undefined" is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is very contradictory. You want to use something that does not exist. You should create your shared object first and flush it, before you can use it. You can put some logic into your app to check if shared object exists and if not, create it with default values that you want. It is basically what you want - some object with default values. Also, you should not use your properties in SO directly at least because you are loosing strong typing. You should create some backed properties in your app and use them. Then, at some point, you can flush these properties into SO.